# Spring Boot: How to pass context from a custom Aspect to Rest Controller Class

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-restcontroller, thread-local

I have defined a custom aspect which does a look up for the resource does few validations and fails fast. If the validations are successful how can I pass on the resource to my Rest Controller class to avoid extra DB lookups

Comment: It is better to add your code segments with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspectClass {

    @Around("execution(* com.example.controller.yourController.yourMethod (SomeClass)) && args(someObject)")
    public Object sendDataToControllerMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, SomeClass someObject) {
        //Do your validation, db related works
        // "someObject" can be filled, changed etc. here
        YourMethodReturnClass yourMethodReturnObject = (YourMethodReturnClass) proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(new Object[] {someObject});
        return yourMethodReturnObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, but the problem with the above approach is I need to change the controller method definition which I don't want do. Ideally I would need is a jersey equivalent URIContext or some kind of thread local which will don't break the existing method signature and parameters.

Comment: Why does this approach make need for controller method change?

Comment: Most of my method arguments are custom java objects. I don't want to pollute those objects by adding the extra info that i want to pass to the controller method.

Comment: How about that: You can use filters. Take necessary data from db and add them as **Request Param** to request. And in your controller methods you can take them as request param, so no need to pollute your objects.

Comment: I considered this option, but the issue with that when i declare the parameter as a Request Param, it shows up in my swagger documentation. And is it critical to me since I will be exposing my API's to external clients. Thats the reason i was mention that i don't want to change method signature.

Comment: If swagger is the only concern, You can make swagger ignore those parameters. **@ApiParam(hidden = true)**

Comment: Swagger was an example and I don't want to add @ApiParam annotations to the tons of API's I have. Also when clients start consuming the API's some kind of security issue might pop in if the try to override the request param(unlikely but there is a chance which I don't want to take) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151433/discussion-between-shoaib627-and-barbakini).